# Create a HTTPS Tunnel to avoid network hard limitations

Tags: network, ssh, vpn, proxy, tunnel

Here is my problem :
At work, if I don't want to use my phone for everything I use the provided connection to the internet, that goes through a network that has strict restrictions : basically all protocols besides HTTPS are blocked. It's been a hassle and has prevented me to work efficiently several times, but despite my complaints to the administration the rules are nowhere near changing.

So what I am thinking I could do :
Create a HTTPS Tunnel to a personal computer at my place (Raspberry pi I just acquired) to be able to do anything I can do from my place.
I am posting the question here because the computer I use between my work and my home runs on macOS.

1. Are there people here that would know if channeling all my connections through such a tunnel could be done (like using a proxy) ?
2. Do you have a better idea ? (Yes I thought about using a VPN, but that protocol is blocked too)

1.st Challenge : I don't know thing one about Tunnels

2.nd Challenge : Connecting the Raspberry Pi at my place to be securely accessible from outside my home network.

Thank you already for enlightening me.

Comment: 3.rd challenge: Not getting fired for circumventing your employer's network protections.

Comment: @MarcWilson I am talking about my personal computer, which can access any network, like when I am connecting it with my phone. The limitation is meant to protect endusers of our network, and I find it lazy to protect it by putting so crippling limits and not to provide a way around for the employees.